# Do I need to escape the character if using an ampersand in button name for Mechanize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm building a small bot that adds a new address to your list of addresses in Amazon.

The code I'm using to submit the form is:

```
button = form.button_with(value: "Save & Continue")
```

Then:

```
next_page = form.submit(button)
```

Doing that is bringing me right back to the same "Enter a New Address" page I was on before when I inspected the page titles.

Do I need to do anything special because of the ampersand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not but if you're worried about it, how about:

```
button = form.button_with(value: /Save.*Continue/)
```